# Property is faster than method? Need reason for it

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, properties

As I google this question so one person give answer that property is faster than method and give one example of `size()` and `length`.

He said length is faster than size because length is property. Can you please let me know is it correct ? Or If you will give example then it will be great for me.

Comment: `size()` was deprecated

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy May I know the meaning of deprecated ?

Comment: @jdsays It was planned to be removed from the library. It can be removed at anytime. So its good to not to use the deprecated functions/properties from a library./

Comment: Which `size()` and `length` are we talking about anyway? Something in jQuery?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes I am asking in jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

`size` internally calls the length

```
//http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// The number of elements contained in the matched element set
        size: function() {
                return this.length;
        },
```

So if you are using length then you are avoiding one extra method call. The [Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/size/) says:

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the **.length property is preferred** because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to get the length of a String or the number of elements in an Array.

`size()` is not a method of the Array or String objects. Thus if it exists some library or you yourself have added this method to the respective prototypes. `length` on the other hand is a default property and (should) exist in any JS runtime.

Unless you cannot use length, the size function will just add unneeded overhead and I would go for the property.

Check the following to links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype

Answer (score 1):

If you will read `length` property then only time required to access an object property will be needed.

However if you will call `size()` then first of all a function will be called, this function will read `length` property internally and then return that value to the caller.

You can clearly see that you are doing the same thing in both cases. But if you call the function then it will include time for calling a function + returning that value too..

Answer (score 0):

Length returns the same thing and is slightly faster according to the jQuery documentation.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/size/